# 'Subarray' as condition to numpy.where()

Tags: python, numpy

To make it clear beforehand: I'm relatively new to python and my 'programming skills' mostly revolve around MATLAB (meaning I can use built-in functions). Hence, I hope that my question is not as stupid as I think it is. That I did not find an answer to it yet means that I either didn't understand my problem myself or that it really is 'something new'.

Enough of the banter: I have extracted an array from an image in which I have stored the pixel values along a regression line that I determined from the image beforehand, leaving a numpy array like `[0,0,0,...,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...]`. Due to some noise, I get some unintended ones along the array, leading to my problem: I want to find the index of the first value after which I can find the subarray `[1,1,1,1,1]` for example. I can't seem to get `numpy.where()` to do that and I must admit that I have absolutely no idea on how to get it to work, efficiently. Manually searching the subarray with a loop is not efficient enough, so using brute force does not work for me, either.

Is there a way to solve this problem in a 'pythonic' way? If so, could you please provide a more or less detailed explanation so that I can understand and reproduce it? I want to think more 'pythonic' but I cannot seem to get into the python-mindset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.cumsum` only provides a solution specific to this problem; I'll try addressing a more general solution for any kind of pattern. You could try thinking of this as a sort of string matching problem. You have a big string (say, your array of 1s and 0s) and a particular noise you want to find, which is 11111. Moreover, you want to find that index where the pattern first appears. This can be done easily in a single line of code, in several ways.

```
import re

def find_idx_of_first_noise(A, N):
    return re.search(''.join(N.astype(str)),''.join(A.astype(str))).start()

A = np.array([0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
N = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])

print(find_idx_of_first_noise(A, noise))
```

Out:

```
7
```

A and N are numpy arrays of integers, so I'm converting them to arrays of strings with `.astype(str)`. I then join the entire arrays of strings into a single string by calling `''.join()`. Thus effectively, I'm running the line: `re.search('11111','0100100111111111').start()`, which finds 11111 in A, and gives me the index of its first occurrence.

Another pythonic way of writing code you should get on top of are list comprehensions. I'll do the above task again in a single line of code:

```
print([i for i in range(len(A)-len(N)+1) if (A[i:i+len(N)]==N).all()][0])
```

Out:

```
7
```

Although convenient, list comprehensions are still a brute force method; it's basically a for loop inside a list.

Now the fastest and most pythonic method in my opinion, is to use tostring.

```
print(A.tostring().index(N.tostring())//A.itemsize)
```

Out:

```
7
```

Make the numpy arrays into bytes strings, then use `.index` to find the position of whatever pattern/noise you have. Divide by the size of the items in A, and you have your result.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.cumsum()` and take the differences between elements 5 indices apart.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(456)  # Make results repeatable

arr= np.random.randint(2, size=100)

arr
# array([1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
#        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
#        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
#        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
#        1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])

cumulate = np.zeros(arr.shape[0]+1, dtype = np.int)
cumulate[1:] = arr.cumsum()   # First item in the array must be zero
diff = cumulate[5:]-cumulate[:-5]

cumulate
# array([ 0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  7,  7,  8,  9,  9, 10,
#        11, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17,
#        17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
#        25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 32, 33,
#        34, 35, 36, 36, 36, 37, 38, 38, 38, 39, 39, 40, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42,
#        43, 44, 44, 45, 46, 47, 47, 48, 48, 49, 49, 50, 50, 51, 52])

np.where( diff == 5 )
# (array([46, 65, 66]),)
```

np.where returns a tuple of arrays so [0][0] to get the required index.

```
np.where(diff == 5)[0][0]
# 46
```